# Fetch user details from Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to fetch users' details from Azure AD using Graph API.

My code is like this :

```
public B2CGraphClient(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenant)
    {

        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        this.tenant = tenant;

        this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant);


        this.credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    }



public string GetUserByObjectId(string objectId)
    {
        return SendGraphGetRequest("/users/" + objectId);
    }

    public string SendGraphGetRequest(string api)
    {

        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", credential);


        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        string url = "https://graph.windows.net/" + tenant + api + "?" + "api-version=1.6";
```

}

But i am gettign an exception at AcquireToken line in SendGraphGetRequest method as -

```
Error validating credentials. Invalid client secret is provided
Inner Exception is :{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}
```

I have provided both - Client ID and Client secret Key, But still getting this exception.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the secret is incorrect. You can regenerate a new secret on Azure portal and use the new secret to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the secret is correct, then make sure that the Application you've registered to use as the service principal has been assigned rights:

[image: Permissions in the portal]

This particular permission requires that you get approval from an AAD administrator before access is granted.

From the [AAD Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds):

**Request the permissions from a directory admin**

When you're ready to request permissions from the organization's admin, you can redirect the user to the v2.0 admin consent endpoint.

```
// Line breaks are for legibility only.

GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions

// Pro tip: Try pasting the following request in a browser!
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```